# Problem while installing pip for python 3.5 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, python3, pip

I have installed pip by using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Then I tried to check the version of pip installed by using:

```
pip --version
```

the output is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in
>   
>       from pip import main ImportError: No module named 'pip'

I used `type pip` command it's output is:

> pip is hashed (/usr/bin/pip)

and the commmand `hash -d pip` doesn't seem to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Have you tried to make python3 the default python?   The package `python-pip` is for default python 2.7  (package python3-pip will load pip3 for python3)

Comment: python 3.5.2 is my default version because when I type python --version it shows python3.5.2

Comment: and installing `python3-pip` does not solve it?

Comment: On Ubuntu the default python should be 2.7 so `python --version` should report a 2.7.x (it reports "2.7.16" for me).  A `python3 --version` reports 3.7.4 for me; so I think you've corrupted your system somehow by making python 3.x the default for `python` instead of python 2.7, and this will cause programs/utils that expect python2 to be default to give errors.

Comment: yes it has worked. I have used the command sudo apt-get install python3-pip

Comment: Perfect. I put it as an answer, please mark it answered.

Answer (score 0):

With Python3 you need to `apt install python3-pip`